The MIT's Introduction to Deep Learning. Lab-1, Part 2: Music Generation with RNNs
There is a great ML course published by Alexander and Ava Amini and Sadhana Lola + others MIT: Introduction to Deep Learning. As a part of that course there is lab published on github Lab1-Part 2.
So in a reason of that my Google Colab works very bad (i can not connect to T4 for hours), I've decided to move notebook to my home laptop. And here is the problem:
Could anyone explain me why same code works at google colab and won't work on my local notebook. I have checked the TF version and mine is 16.2, in compare with G-Colab's 15.0. The tf.keras.layers.Embedding function's signature seems to be the same, and yet I have no idea how to fix this problem... :
### Defining the RNN Model ###

'''TODO: Add LSTM and Dense layers to define the RNN model using the Sequential API.'''
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Layer 1: Embedding layer to transform indices into dense vectors
    #   of a fixed embedding size
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),

    # Layer 2: LSTM with `rnn_units` number of units.
    # TODO: Call the LSTM function defined above to add this layer.
    LSTM(rnn_units=rnn_units),

    # Layer 3: Dense (fully-connected) layer that transforms the LSTM output
    #   into the vocabulary size.
    # TODO: Add the Dense layer.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=vocab_size,
                          activation='softmax')
  ])

  return model

# Build a simple model with default hyperparameters. You will get the
#   chance to change these later.
model = build_model(len(vocab), embedding_dim=256, rnn_units=1024, batch_size=32)

The errors that mine Notebook is show are follwoing:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 25
     21   return model
     23 # Build a simple model with default hyperparameters. You will get the
     24 #   chance to change these later.
---> 25 model = build_model(len(vocab), embedding_dim=256, rnn_units=1024, batch_size=32)

Cell In[16], line 8, in build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size)
      4 def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
      5   model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      6     # Layer 1: Embedding layer to transform indices into dense vectors
      7     #   of a fixed embedding size
----> 8     tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
      9 
     10     # Layer 2: LSTM with `rnn_units` number of units.
     11     # TODO: Call the LSTM function defined above to add this layer.
     12     LSTM(rnn_units=rnn_units),
     13 
     14     # Layer 3: Dense (fully-connected) layer that transforms the LSTM output
     15     #   into the vocabulary size.
     16     # TODO: Add the Dense layer.
     17     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=vocab_size,
     18                           activation='softmax')
     19   ])
     21   return model

File ~/miniconda3/envs/gpt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/core/embedding.py:93, in Embedding.__init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer, embeddings_regularizer, embeddings_constraint, mask_zero, weights, lora_rank, **kwargs)
     89 if input_length is not None:
     90     warnings.warn(
     91         "Argument `input_length` is deprecated. Just remove it."
     92     )
---> 93 super().__init__(**kwargs)
     94 self.input_dim = input_dim
     95 self.output_dim = output_dim

File ~/miniconda3/envs/gpt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py:266, in Layer.__init__(self, activity_regularizer, trainable, dtype, autocast, name, **kwargs)
    264     self._input_shape_arg = input_shape_arg
    265 if kwargs:
--> 266     raise ValueError(
    267         "Unrecognized keyword arguments "
    268         f"passed to {self.__class__.__name__}: {kwargs}"
    269     )
    271 self._path = None  # Will be determined in `build_wrapper`
    272 self.built = False

ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Embedding: {'batch_input_shape': [32, None]}


# It works
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM

def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        # Layer 1
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_shape=(None,)),

        # Layer 2
        LSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True),

        # Layer 3
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
    ])

    return model

vocab = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # Just a placeholder for the vocab list
model = build_model(len(vocab), embedding_dim=256, rnn_units=1024, batch_size=32)
model.summary()


Please format your answer properly.

why does this work and the question doesn't? what changes have you made to their code?
